# A cryptic message when converting a Graph to Graphics

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, conversion, message-coding

In Mathematica 13.3 (Windows 11) I do

```
Graph[{1, 2}, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2]
```

then right-click on the result and choose "Convert To Graphics" from the menu that appears. Conversion is done seemingly successfully but the following message is generated under the output:

```
Set::write: Tag Inherited in Inherited[State] is Protected.
```

Stack trace is

```
Message[Set::write, Inherited, Inherited["State"]]

Inherited["State"] = "ProgressIndicator"

Inherited["State"] = "ProgressIndicator"; Inherited
```

What does it all mean?

Comment: In the meantime, as a workaround you can do `FullGraphics[Graph[{1, 2}, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2]]` or just use `Show` or even `GraphPlot`

Comment: The undocumented function ```GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics[%]```  also seems to work. It looks like a bug in Mathematica, but I can't see where.